# How to retrieve Strings from Shared Preference using GSON?

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences, gson

I am saving my

```
"ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();"
```

using GSON in Shared Preference with below code which is working fine

```
protected static void saveItems(){
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("prefName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("myList", new Gson().toJson(items).toString());
        editor.apply();
    }
```

Retrieval

```
protected void retreiveItems(){
    preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("prefName",android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    saveitems = preferences.getString("myList", "");
    Log.d("LOG", "Retreived Items : " + saveitems);
}
```

But retrieving is again giving JSON format.

```
Retreived Items : [{"subtitle":"20 Nov 2013 12:35:19","title":"Sync Successful"},{"subtitle":"20 Nov 2013 12:35:44","title":"Sync Successful"}]
```

How can i extract each JSON set into two different strings so that i can add it into my listview

```
items.add(new EntryItem(title, subtitle));
```

Comment: You should check the value you put in Preference first. new Gson().toJson(items).toString()->What it gives you?

Comment: `How can i extract each JSON set into two different strings so that i can add it into my listview.` Besides saving it into two different strings its better you parse it and store it into custom arraylist creating POJO class.

Answer (score 0):

You can populate json array directly to EntryItem class object instead getting one by one string. gson will give you array of EntryItem[].

For Example your EntryItem class is as below

```
public class EntryItem {

    private String subtitle;
    private String title;
       // setter getter here
}
```

You can now parse json string like this

```
EntryItem[] items = gson.fromJson(reader, EntryItem[].class);
```

subtiltle is date in json format, Entry item will also give as it as date in string format, you can change your format according to you

**If you want that Gson will change your date format during parsing then you have to do as below**

```
final GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonDeserializer<Date>() {

            final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss");

            @Override
            public Date deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT,
                    final JsonDeserializationContext context)
                    throws JsonParseException {
                try {
                    System.out.println(json.getAsString());
                    return df.parse(json.getAsString());
                } catch (final java.text.ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }
        });

        EntryItem[] items = builder.create().fromJson(reader, EntryItem[].class);
```